# How to insert values in certain row from PHP

Tags: php, insert

I have the following array that is describing my table header:

```
$aColumns = array( 'time1.Time', 'time2.Time' , 'time1.id' , 'time1.Signal' , 'v.Name' , 'v.Lastname'  );
```

I want to insert new values in the `time1.id` column.

When I process the following code I got my data shown in the first column which is `time1.Time` and I need it to be in column `time1.id` why is this happening?

Here is the code:

```
if ( mysql_num_rows( $rResult ) > 0 )
    {
        $aCols = array_keys( mysql_fetch_assoc( $rResult ) );
        mysql_data_seek($rResult, 0);
        $id= array_search( 'time1.id', $aCols );        
        $value= "NEW_VALUE";

        while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_row( $rResult ) ) 
        { 
            $aRow[$id] = $value;
            $aOutput['aaData'][] = $aRow; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `id` as the column name instead of `time1.id`. Usually only the column names are returned as keys in the result array , even if you have specified the table names in the select fields.

```
$id= array_search( 'id', $aCols );
```

Comment: this is not working correctly. now I have new values inserted in the second column which is `time2.time`, my `time1.id` is showing me my ID's instead of new values

Comment: this is the output `Array
(
    [0] => Time
    [1] => id
    [2] => Signal
    [3] => Name
    [4] => Lastname
  `

Comment: I don't know how is this possible because I have put `id` in the column three??

Comment: As i said in the answer only one `time` column is returned when using `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Better modify your `SELECT` query and change `time2.Time` to `time2.Time AS time2`. Then it will work.

Comment: Otherwise you should use `$id= array_search( 'time1.id', $aColumns);` i.e. change `$aCols` to `$aColumns` . Changing the select fields is better though.